# Value assigned to a long property in Biztalk orchestration is not valid

Tags: biztalk, long-integer

I am getting the following error in Biztalk...

```
The value assigned to property 'https://blah.Schemas.PropertySchema:sequenceNumber' is not valid: '15'.

Error:
Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'blah.Orchestrations.CommitDispatcher(3d0134b5-83b1-1fb7-c6b0-5d6fa4614373)'.
The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated. 
If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
InstanceId: 4da93c1f-7303-4052-adf4-976afcdda1cf
Shape name: SetSequence
ShapeId: 3909c37f-092e-419d-864d-4a0cb5a7c03e
Exception thrown from: segment 1, progress 134
Inner exception: The value assigned to property 'https://blah.Schemas.PropertySchema:sequenceNumber' is not valid: '15'.

Exception type: InvalidPropertyValueException
Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.Engine
Target Site: Microsoft.BizTalk.Agent.Interop.IBTMessage PrepareMessage(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.XLANGMessage, System.Collections.IList, System.Collections.IList)
```

This is the schema which I'm using to set the above long value...

```
<ns0:SetSequenceNumber xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">  
  <ns0:transactionId>transactionId_0</ns0:transactionId>  
  <ns0:sequenceNumber>10/<ns0:sequenceNumber>  
</ns0:SetSequenceNumber>
```

The datatype of `sequenceNumber` is `xs:long`.

Could someone please help me understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this an outright bug in Biztalk (I've had this BizTalk 2009 as well)

Yossi Dahan talks about this [here](http://blog.sabratech.co.uk/2006_10_01_archive.html)

The workaround I've used is just to change the type on the correlation to xs:string.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem in BTS2016 :-(
I used nonNegativeInteger, that also works. Seams like nonNegativeInteger works with int64 variables in orchestrations.